# Angular Factory Provider with a Dynamic Parameter

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, dependency-injection, angular7

I have the following provider factory for a dynamically calculated firebase firestore path:

```
const meetingServiceFactory = (db: AngularFirestore, authService: AuthService ) => {

  const userId = authService.user;
  return new MeetingService('/users/' + userId + '/meetings', db);

};

export let meetingServiceProvider =   { provide: MeetingService,
                                        useFactory: meetingServiceFactory,
                                        deps: [AngularFirestore, AuthService] };
```

Here is `MeetingService`:

```
@Injectable(
  {
    providedIn: 'root'
  }
)
export class MeetingService extends FirestoreDataService<Meeting> {

  constructor(path: string, db: AngularFirestore) {
    super(path, db);
  }


  setProposalFlag(meetingKey: string) {
    return from(this.db.doc(this.path + `/${meetingKey}`).update({hasProposal: true})
      .then(result => console.log('changed active Flag on meeting: ', result))
      .catch(err => console.log(err)));
  }

  saveMeeting(meeting: Meeting) {

    return of(meeting).pipe(
      map(meetingToSave =>  {
       return  {...meetingToSave, key: this.db.createId() };
      }),
      switchMap( finalMeeting => this.addItemWithKey(finalMeeting.key, finalMeeting) )
    );
  }

  getAll() {
    return this.getItems();
  }
}
```

This inherits from `FirestoreDataService<T>` so that I have kind of a CRUD Service to reuse:

```
@Injectable()
export class FirestoreDataService<T> {

  protected itemCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<T>;
  protected items$: Observable<T[]>;
  protected snapshot$: Observable<DocumentChangeAction<T>[]>;
  protected state$: Observable<DocumentChangeAction<T>[]>;

  constructor(protected path: string, protected db: AngularFirestore) {
    this.itemCollection = this.db.collection<T>(path);
    this.items$ = this.itemCollection.valueChanges();
    this.snapshot$ = this.itemCollection.snapshotChanges();
    this.state$ = this.itemCollection.stateChanges();
  }

  getItems(): Observable<T[]> {
    return this.items$;
  }

  getItemWithKey( key: string): Observable<T> {
    // used to use stateChanges here.
    // as the doc states, this only emits recent changes,
    // so if we subscribe in an async pipe, it will not reemit and subsequent observables will be empty.
    return this.itemCollection.doc<T>(key).valueChanges();
  }

  addItem(data: T) {
    return from(this.itemCollection.add(data)
                                          .catch(err => console.log('Error while adding item: ', err)));
  }

  addItemWithKey(key: string, data: T) {
    return from(this.itemCollection.doc(key).set(data)
                                          .catch(err => console.log('Error while adding item: ', err)));
  }

  deleteItem(key: string) {
    return from(this.itemCollection.doc(key).delete()
                                          .catch(err => console.log('Error while deleting item: ', err)));
  }
}
```

, but it obviously depends on runtime decisions on the userId. Seems to work fine within `ng serve` but on transpiling for prod, I get: `ERROR in : Can't resolve all parameters for FirestoreDataService in /web-client/src/app/core/services/firestore-data.service.ts: (?, [object Object]).`

I assume that is because I do not know the exact path at compile time. Is that so? If not, what could be the issue with this setup? And how would I fix it/improve it? I run Angular 7 at the moment. Thanks for help!

Comment: did you try removing `@Injectable()` decorator from  `FirestoreDataService`? Since you are instantiating the class instance yourself anyway, without Angular DI.

Comment: @BorysKupar. Yes, tried that. Did not work.

Comment: Is it the same error shown in that case?

Comment: How do you use `meetingServiceProvider` ?

Comment: @BorysKupar Yes, same error. I inject it in my module: `providers: [ FormBuilder, MeetingForm, meetingServiceProvider, GeocodingService ]
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem through refactoring. Here's in the hope it's useful for someone.

1. [Angular docs on DI](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-providers) provide extensive documentation of how to use the injector, which also is useful in testing.
2. However, there is no description for my exact use case, because DI needs to have defined parameters at transpile time. Compare this to a framework like, e.g. Spring where you could do value injection when the context starts up. Silly old me thought that this would be the same here, but of course, even Spring needs to have defined beans when starting up.
3. In consequence, when the transpiler (including aot) cannot decide where a parameter should come from, it throws an error.

If anyone is interested, here is how I refactored my MeetingService:

```
@Injectable(
  {
    providedIn: 'root'
  }
)
export class MeetingService extends FirestoreDataService<Meeting> {

   constructor(authService: AuthService,
          db: AngularFirestore) {
     const path = `/users/${authService.user}/meetings`;
     super(path, db);
     this.auth = authService;
   }

...

}
```

Please note that this only works because injecting services this way, the parameters are private to the constructor otherwise, the first call would have to be `super(path, db);`